# Stream processed opencv video to android application

Tags: android, c++, opencv, video, streaming

I am looking for the best way to stream post-processed video captured by a Beaglebone black, over the network and displayed on an Android tablet. The beaglebone app is written in c/c++ and Android app is in Java.

My goal is to (1) capture video (2) apply background subtraction to detect motion, etc (3) stream video over the local network (4) display video in Android app. I want this to work where the user can click a button and near-realtime video starts playing.

I have already tried simply continuously capturing frames and saving to a file, capture.jpg. Next, I start a simple http server with python. The Android app then continuously downloads and displays the image. This is slow and jumpy but it does work. I would like to get it closer to  "near-realtime".

I have looked into mjpeg streaming but I'm not sure how easy it is to get opencv to output post-processed frames into mjpeg format or displaying the mjpeg images in an Android imageview or videoview.

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this would be greatly appreciated.